# Override a css property in Dojo

Tags: javascript, css, dojo

I am working in enhanced grid Dojo 1.10 version. My problem is very simple but still, I am not able to resolve it. I need to apply background-color css property
to a table row. But the problem there is an already background property applied to that row which has background-color also. If I remove that property from console my background-color is reflecting properly.

I have tried to override it, change it but none of them is working. Actually the class which is applied is not directly straight forward. Something like this

```
.claro .dojoxGridRowTable tr {
background-image : url("...")
background-repeat : repeat-x;
background-attachment :scroll;
background-clip:border-box;
background-origin:padding-box;
background-size:auto auto;
}
```

How can I override this class. Can anyone please help me here.

Comment: use `class` in row

Comment: you can define your own class and then apply it to the table. This way dojo uses your custom class rather than OOTB

Comment: How can apply class only to tr element? I am using the same class that dojo uses but no reflecting. I am even using precedence in css then also it is not using my custom css

Comment: try like                                                       
           .yourtablecontainer-valueCell {
 padding-left: 2px;
 background-color: #72bdd5;
 width: 0%;
 text-align:center;
}
.yourtablecontainer-labelCell {
 background-color: #7d3db080;
 padding-left: 20px;
 width: 20%;
 text-align:center;
}

Comment: here you are saying having table id and cell value in class itself?

Answer (score 0):

The root of the problem is Specificity. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

Basically, the more selectors you use in your CSS, the higher it will rank in specificity. For example,

```
 .text-title {}
```

is not very specific.

```
 .label-text .text-title {}
```

is more specific and will take precedence.

```
 .label .label-text .text-title {}
```

is even more specific. And:

```
 div.label > .label-text > .text-title {}
```

is yet even more specific and will take precedence over all the others.

So the solution to the problem is that your CSS needs to get more specific than the Dojo CSS. Just use more specific ones in your custom CSS.

Unfortunately, you may see properties with !important in a number of situations, so you will be forced to use it as well to over ride theirs.

Answer (score 0):

use !important on CSS properties:

```
.claro .dojoxGridRowTable tr {
background-image : url("...") !important;
background-repeat : repeat-x !important;
background-attachment :scroll !important;
background-clip:border-box !important;
background-origin:padding-box !important;
background-size:auto auto !important;
}
```